# Redirect http to https for domain not for IP by htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, server

I have API's that are IP based and I want HTTP to https for domain only not for IP based URLs. These codes work for both IP and domain but I don't want to apply https on IP. please help me thanks.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Add a RewriteCond that checks what HTTP_HOST contains.

Answer (score 0):

Change the current code, to:

---

### Method 1

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Change `!^127\.0\.0\.1$` to your IP address.

For example:

If your IP address is 172.16.254.1 change it to `!^172\.16\.254\.1$`

---

***OR***

---

### Method 2

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Change example.com to your domain.

---

Feel free to let me know if it worked or not. Happy Coding!